# jquery prev - with selector

Tags: jquery

Why does the following code change all of the TDs in the table with the class=dupegroup red?  The TD that fires the click event has a checkbox in it. I want to know the value of the first TD in the row so I put a class=dupegroup on it. The ajax call updates the database. This is just a test so I could figure out a way to get the value of the first TD.

```
$('.notdupe').live('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=SetNotDupe",
      data: "indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"),
      error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      }
    });
        $('td').prev('.dupegroup').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
```

---

*adding HTML from comment...*

```
<td class="dupegroup">#dupe_group_number#</td> 
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="UserIDList" value="#userid#"/>
</td> 
<td>
    <a href="#request.controlURL#individuals/?fa=viewIndiv&dkey=#userid#" target="_blank">
        #userid# 
</td> 
<td>#lastname#</td> 
<td>#firstname#</td> 
<td>#nickname#</td> 
<td>#companyname#</td> 
<td>#address1#</td> 
<td>#zipcode#</td> 
<td>#state#</td> 
<td align="center">
    <input class="notdupe" type="checkbox" name="indivID" value="#userid#" checked />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @am not i am  said should work but if you already have a unique way to grab it...why not just write it like this

```
$('td.dupegroup').css({'background-color', 'red'});
```

Comment: alternatively it probably could have been like this as well $(this).parent('tr').find('.dupegroup')

Answer (score 2):

> *"Why does the following code change all of the TDs"*

Because you're selecting all the `td` elements with `$('td')`.

Use `$(this).prev('.dupegroup')` instead, or if the `.dupgroup` isn't directly adjacent, use `$(this).prevAll('.dupgroup')`.

Comment: Didn't work  $(this).prevAll('.dupegroup').css('background-color', 'red');

Comment: @user990016: `.notdupe` is a TD element? Post your HTML. It's really hard to give help if you don't provide the relevant information. Since your question is about DOM selection/traversal, the only way to give an accurate answer is to see the DOM you're working with.

Comment: <td class="dupegroup">#dupe_group_number#</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="UserIDList" value="#userid#"/></td>
<td><a href="#request.controlURL#individuals/?fa=viewIndiv&dkey=#userid#" target="_blank">#userid# </td>
<td>#lastname#</td> 
<td>#firstname#</td> 
<td>#nickname#</td>
<td>#companyname#</td> 
<td>#address1#</td>
<td>#zipcode#</td>
<td>#state#</td>
<td align="center"><input class="notdupe" type="checkbox" name="indivID" value="#userid#" checked /></td>

Comment: @user990016: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.dupegroup')`

Comment: @user990016: Not really sure what you mean, but it shouldn't have any effect. I added your HTML to your question.